# Delphi TChart Bar Offsets

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe6

By default, the biggest value in the chart will have a full bar from bottom to top.

[image]

Is there a way to get some space between the top of the diagram and the maximum value? I wanted to have a standard zoom of 90% or something like this, but zooming out any further is not possible.

Comment: You can always set the axis ranges in code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I would appreciate a code example, it's my first time working with TCharts so I don't really have a clue how to do so...

Comment: Since you know the maximum value, you can set the range of the axis to fit your need.

Comment: Set `Chart1.Axis.Left.Automatic := false` to turn off the auto-scaling. Then set `Chart1.Axis.Left.Maximum := xxx`, where `xxx` is 1.0/0.9*SeriesMax, if you want a 90% margin within the axis.

Comment: @LURD the MinimumOffset and MaximumOffset properties, as I wrote in my answer, are specially designed for this purpose and much easier to use.

Comment: @NarcísCalvet, I agree, I was only responding to how to set the axis ranges in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using axis MaximumOffset property. For example:

```
  Chart1.Axes.Left.MaximumOffset:=25;
```

Comment: ok, I'll change the question title cause this solves my problem but isn't related to zoom (:

Answer (score 1):

As @Narcis Calvet sad one option is to use MaximumOffset but another option is to use:

```
Chart1.Axes.Left.Increment := 20;
```

I prefer to use Increments instead of MaximumOffset becouse usually it reults in nicer numerical scale on the side.

EDIT: To learn more about controlling the TChart Axis controll check this site:
http://wiki.teechart.net/index.php?title=VCLTutorial4

Comment: in my case the maximumOffset is much more useful, because a fixed increment doesn't make sense (because my values might differ quite much), and I wanted to refrain from code changes just for the design

Comment: @FlorianKoch it's worth checking the tutorial about axes settings mentioned on this answer.

Comment: yeah, the link was really useful